# naturally graded algebras

Tags: lie-algebras, graded-rings, graded-algebras

I found a good explanation on graded algebras [Understanding of graded algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50164/understanding-of-graded-algebra)

But I am confused about difference between "**naturally graded**" and "**graded**".
May you please clarify the notion of naturally graded with an example.

Let consider Lie algebra $sl_2$ over field of characteristic $0$. We have, for example, $\mathbb{Z}$, ${\mathbb{Z}}_{2} \times {\mathbb{Z}}_{2} $ and ${\mathbb{Z}}_{2} $ grading for that. Do mentioned grading are naturally grading? Does a naturally graded mean $\mathbb{N}$-grading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Naturally graded" is not a technical term; it is entirely informal and has no precise meaning.  It just means that the grading "arises naturally" rather than being some artificial ad hoc grading that someone made up.